# Kubernetes rolling update with different image

Tags: kubernetes

Suppose my deployment is having mysql:5.6 image .
Is it possible (does kubernetes support) to do rolling update for my deployment  with image nginx:1.14.0?

Comment: can you explain yourself? you want to trigger an update by changing the image?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only if the deployment doesn't rely on specific image (use content of specific image). For example, use the following yaml. But I don't think there's such scenarios in practice.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: demo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: mysql:5.6
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is yes. 
I have tried that on dev and staging servers. What you are asking for is container name changing in addition to the version. 
In fact, you can change the entire url to fetch the image from.